# Mouseenter children flash on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to show the navigation bar when I mouse over the slider. The navigation bar is inside it as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/warface/GhY3R/2/

How to avoid that glitch when my mouse is over the nav bar ?

```
$(function(){    
/* Slider nav mouseover thingy*/
    $('#slider').mouseenter(function(e){
        $('.portfolio nav').show();
    });
    $('#slider').mouseleave(function(e){
        $('.portfolio nav').hide();
    });
});


<div class="portfolio">    
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <nav>
        <a class="next" data-slider="slider" rel="next">▶</a>
        <a class="prev" data-slider="slider" rel="prev">◀</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GhY3R/3/)

```
$(function(){    
  /* Slider nav mouseover thing*/
  $('#slider,nav').mouseenter(function(e){
     $('.portfolio nav').show();
  });
  $('#slider').mouseleave(function(e){
     $('.portfolio nav').hide();
  });
});
```